# Meilisearch version [Error: Your database version (1.0.2) is incompatible with your current engine version (1.1.0).]

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-10, meilisearch

When I start the run docker and meilisearch container doesn't run with this error :

> 2023-04-10 17:23:44 Error: Your database version (1.0.2) is incompatible with your current engine version (1.1.0).
> 2023-04-10 17:23:44 To migrate data between Meilisearch versions, please follow our guide on https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/update_and_migration/updating.html

When I run my project yesterday everything was good but today I can't start the run meilisearch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using `meilisearch:latest` for your docker container? If so your container was probably updated but your index is still the older version.

Comment: @paul41 I am running into the same issue after doing a `sail down --rmi all`, then `sail up -d` to start fresh. If the "index" (whatever that is) is still the older version, how can we fix it?

Comment: You can update with a dump https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/advanced/dumps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same error after having an outdated docker image of meilisearch (getmeili/meilisearch) and deleting it to fetch the new one. As the meilisearch volume/database was created using the old image, it was also outdated and this is why you are getting this incompatibility error. In order to fix it, I removed the volume using `docker volume rm <volume-name>`

(you can list all the volumes with `docker volume ls`)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I created a second project that used Laravel Sail.

The `docker-compose.yml` uses the `:latest` meilisearch image, so when I built the new project for the first time, it updated the version of the meilisearch image that sail uses, which has changed since I installed the first project.

Meilisearch data needs to run on the same engine version it was created with, so this mismatch caused the above error.

You need to export a dump, update meili, and then import that dump. Or if you don't care about the data, you can just delete the volume and run `sail up` to rebuild.